# Which Windows service controls displaying the activation status in Settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I disabled almost all non-essential services using System Configuration (msconfig). Almost everything is still working, but the Settings app is no longer showing the activation status:
[image: Windows activation status blank]

However, slmgr and Get-CimInstance still correctly reports activation status. The event log does not indicate any failure. Which service controls displaying the activation status in Settings? It is known that enabling the following services does not have an effect:

- Windows Management Instrumentation (essential for slmgr)
- Windows License Manager Service
- Client License Service
- Windows Update, Update Orchestrator Service, Windows Modules Installer
- All services beginning with "Network"
- COM+ Services
- Windows Event Log, Windows Event Collector, Windows Error Reporting

Answer (score 0):

After trying all kinds of combinations of services, and checking the list of running services of a normal system, the correct answer has been determined to be: **Web Account Manager**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).